# How to use the RtlCaptureStackBackTrace() in Kernel32.dll library?

Tags: c#, interop, dllimport

I know about the `StackTrace` class but for what I am doing this is too slow due to all the symbol lookups.

I heard about the `RtlCaptureStackBackTrace` function in `Kernel32.dll` but I seem to be unable to get it to function correctly.  I am unfamiliar with pinvoke as I rarely have to do anything with it and the stuff I do is well covered on the net, this is not however :(.

This is the definition I have:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern ushort RtlCaptureStackBackTrace(uint FramesToSkip, uint FramesToCapture, out IntPtr BackTrace, out uint BackTraceHash);
```

And this is how I am using it:

```
IntPtr trace = IntPtr.Zero;
uint traceHash = 0; 
int framesCaptured = 0;

framesCaptured = RtlCaptureStackBackTrace(0, 4, out trace, out traceHash);

int[] frames = new int[framesCaptured];
Marshal.Copy(trace, frames, 0, framesCaptured);
```

What I see is that framesCaptured is 1, which should be at least 4 user calls plus system calls for my test app.

EDIT: I should probably be explicit in that my question is what am I doing wrong with `RtlCaptureStackBackTrace` that I am not receiving the correct stack address information or am I using it right and just don't know how to disseminate the data?

Comment: It will not work in managed environment. Explanation is here: http://win32easy.blogspot.in/2011/03/rtlcapturestackbacktrace-in-managed.html

Comment: Your right, thanks.  Conversely I just found out about a cool feature [CallerMemberName] which will work just as well for me.

Comment: Yes it has been newly introduced in .Net 4.5. Had you specified this requirement in original problem statement you would have got the answer soon enough :)